# Android and the java server build a long connection with web socket and how to send a packet

Tags: java, android

```
public class TestDatabean {
    public static int count = 0;
    public int id;
    public volatile static int data;
}
```

The above "data" is covered once every 5 seconds.

---

The value after the coverage is not obtained in websocket (obtained every 5 seconds)  TestDatabean.getTestDatabean().getData()

```
 final WebSocketOneWayTest client  = (WebSocketOneWayTest)connect.get(key);
                     task = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {  

   TestDatabean.getTestDatabean().getData()；

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

}